# Rename category part the permalink without .htaccess

Tags: permalinks

I have pretty permalinks that look like this:

http://mysite.com/category/my-blog-post/

I want to rename "category" into "company-news", to make it look like this:

http://mysite.com/company-news/my-blog-post/

I know I could use .htaccess file for that, but it would mess with the PageRank. Is there an alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

Settings > Permalinks, Change the "Category Base" section to company-news.